# Can I park at JFK and use AirTrain if I am not flying?

Tags: automobiles, new-york-city, jfk

I'm seeing a show in NYC on Sat. (driving in from Virginia) and looking for the best place to park, i.e. not NYC. My husband suggested parking at JFK Airport. Can I park there and take AirTrain to Howard Beach subway station if I'm not flying from JFK?

Answer (score 16):

Nothing in the Port Authority's [JFK parking rates and information](http://www.panynj.gov/airports/airport-parking-jfk-rates-info.html) page says anything about parking being reserved for passengers; certainly, I have never seen or heard of anyone being asked to present a boarding pass or other proof that you are there to do business at the airport.

---

But if you're coming from Virginia to go to a show in Manhattan, parking at JFK is an *absolutely atrocious* idea. JFK is in Queens, so you're overshooting, crossing two bodies of water for the privilege with all the tolls and traffic that entails, and then backtracking an hour via AirTrain, LIRR, and subway.

For Broadway shows, I've parked before at the [Port Authority Bus Terminal](http://www.panynj.gov/bus-terminals/pabt-services.html), which is walking distance from the theatre district. At $35 for 12 hours, it's reasonable by Manhattan standards. But presumably you wanted to avoid the multiple hassles of driving into Manhattan in the first place, in which case you should seek parking on the New Jersey side, perhaps at an [NJ Transit station](http://www.njtransit.com/rg/rg_servlet.srv?hdnPageAction=StationParkRideTo) on a line with service to New York Penn Station. Rates will be cheaper than for [EWR parking](https://www.panynj.gov/airports/airport-parking-ewr-rates-info.html), and you avoid having to pay AirTrain fare.

I don't know how many people are in your party are coming up from Virginia, but if it's just one or two, you might also consider taking one of the numerous DC-NYC bus services, which can get you there for under $50 round trip— less than tolls, gas, and parking would be for a small party. Amtrak is faster, more reliable, and more comfortable, but not price-competitive with the buses.

Comment: Indeed, Chinatown buses from DC-NY run around $25 each way, and there's one that even goes all the way down to Richmond. I wouldn't drive this.

Comment: These Chinatown buses are also notoriously not very safe...  My sister was on one of those from Boston to NY that overturned around Hartford.  Luckily she was ok, just shocked.  And the compensation?  $20 - the cost of the ticket.

Comment: When coming via PA/NJ (and points south), parking at [Secaucus Junction](http://www.njtransit.com/rg/rg_servlet.srv?hdnPageAction=TrainStationLookupFrom&selStation=38174) and taking the train in is insanely easy.  By far the easiest NYC trip I ever did.

Comment: I agree with Aleks G don't take the crazy Chinatown bus.  Greyhound has many more buses going to NYC, only a little bit more expensive ($5 as of 2010 from BOS to NYC), and a much better track record.